# regex syntax javafx

Tags: java, regex, escaping, javafx

A silly question, I am not sure what is wrong in the following javafx regex syntax. Netbeans complains illegal escape character in whole of this regex string,

```
var pattern:String = "(\/S*)(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:\{0,1\}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch.

Cheers,
Abi

Answer (score 2):

Try this double \\ for \

var pattern:String = "(\\/S*)(ftp|http|https):\\/\\/(\\w+:\{0,1\}\\w*@)?(\\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\\/|\\/([\\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\\/]))?";

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is here:

```
(\/S*)(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:\{0,1\}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?
                                -------
```

I assume what you want to say is there can be a ":" or not. Therefor you don't need to escape the brackets, i.e. only `:{0,1}`, but this is simply `:?`

So I assume you mean:

```
(\/S*)(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:?\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?
```